# create columns representing 4 week period from weekly data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of weekly data. The date are the first day of each week. The dataframe look like below:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame( {'date': ['2019-12-22', '2019-12-15', '2019-12-08', '2019-12-01',
                            '2019-11-24', '2019-11-17', '2019-11-10', '2019-11-03',
                            '2019-10-27', '2019-10-20', '2019-10-13'],
                    'p': list((df.index+4)//4) })

    date        p
0   2019-12-22  1
1   2019-12-15  1
2   2019-12-08  1
3   2019-12-01  1
4   2019-11-24  2
5   2019-11-17  2
6   2019-11-10  2
7   2019-11-03  2
8   2019-10-27  3
9   2019-10-20  3
10  2019-10-13  3
```

I need to create a column p2 as last week of every 4 week period.
And also another column showing date range for each period. 
Look like below:

```
    date        p   p1           p2
0   2019-12-22  1   2019-12-22  2019-11-24: 2019-12-22
1   2019-12-15  1   2019-12-22  2019-11-24: 2019-12-22
2   2019-12-08  1   2019-12-22  2019-11-24: 2019-12-22
3   2019-12-01  1   2019-12-22  2019-11-24: 2019-12-22
4   2019-11-24  2   2019-11-24  2019-10-27: 2019-11-24
5   2019-11-17  2   2019-11-24  2019-10-27: 2019-11-24
6   2019-11-10  2   2019-11-24  2019-10-27: 2019-11-24
7   2019-11-03  2   2019-11-24  2019-10-27: 2019-11-24
8   2019-10-27  3   2019-10-27  2019-10-13: 2019-10-27
9   2019-10-20  3   2019-10-27  2019-10-13: 2019-10-27
10  2019-10-13  3   2019-10-27  2019-10-13: 2019-10-27
```

Does anyone knows how to achieve that?

Comment: you are creating df, and referencing it in column 'p'? could you have a look at your original dataframe and fix it?

Comment: does `p` column indicate the week group?

Comment: I think you might be able to use some kind of groupby to groupby column `p`. Another way is to use modulus operations and slicing by column `p`. This only applies if the data is given in the format as you described in your question. However, I think using Pandas Time Series native/datetime operations would probably be the most fruitful way to approach this problem

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understand, you can give the below a try:

```
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date']) #convert to datetime
g = df.groupby('p') # group on column p

df['p1'] =g['date'].transform('max') # gets the last date for the group
df['p2'] = (df['p'].map(g['date'].max().shift(-1)).fillna(g['date'].transform('last'))
            .astype(str).add(' : ' + df['p1'].astype(str)))
```

---

```
print(df)
         date  p         p1                       p2
0  2019-12-22  1 2019-12-22  2019-11-24 : 2019-12-22
1  2019-12-15  1 2019-12-22  2019-11-24 : 2019-12-22
2  2019-12-08  1 2019-12-22  2019-11-24 : 2019-12-22
3  2019-12-01  1 2019-12-22  2019-11-24 : 2019-12-22
4  2019-11-24  2 2019-11-24  2019-10-27 : 2019-11-24
5  2019-11-17  2 2019-11-24  2019-10-27 : 2019-11-24
6  2019-11-10  2 2019-11-24  2019-10-27 : 2019-11-24
7  2019-11-03  2 2019-11-24  2019-10-27 : 2019-11-24
8  2019-10-27  3 2019-10-27  2019-10-13 : 2019-10-27
9  2019-10-20  3 2019-10-27  2019-10-13 : 2019-10-27
10 2019-10-13  3 2019-10-27  2019-10-13 : 2019-10-27
```